# Convert 24 hour time into 12 hour time: edX course Basics of Computing and Programming, branching II

Tags: python

When I enter a time below 12 hours on this it comes up with an error (converting any time to 12). So 3:15am would become 12:15 am.

Any ideas?

```
print("Please enter time in 24 hour format:")
hour_24=int(input("Please write hours in military/24 hour time"))
minutes=int(input("Please write the minute(s) in minute format"))

if (0 <= hour_24 <= 11):
    period = "am"
    if (hour_24==0):
        hour_12=12
    else: 
        hour_12=hour_24
else:
    period = "pm"
    if (hour_24==12):
        hour12=12
    else:
        hour12=hour_24-12

print(hour_24, ":", minutes, " is ", hour12, ":", minutes, " ", period, sep="")
```

Comment: The problem is that one variable you have named `hour_12` and the other you have named `hour12`. Make it so they are all the same and it will work.

Comment: Thank you!! Pretty new to this but such a simple thing to spend like an hour on

Comment: We've all been there